# How do I make the bmatrix bigger as it looks very tiny on my document?

Tags: matrices, tag

I have tried using `\renewarraystretch{1.2}` as suggested by Dan in another post but it only stretched the matrix and not the content of it. How may I make the actual partial derivatives bigger as well as making sure it does not exceed the matrix height. When I used dfrac instead of the `\physics` package, the content of the matrix exceeded the brackets. I have excess code in here because it needs to also be present in the align arrangement.

Also, there is an issue with the tag for some reason, which did not occur anywhere else. The error says "ams math error: Multiple \tag" even though I did not write `\tag{15}` anywhere else. Consequently, it complies with (14) in the second equation when it should be in the first and the second should have (15)

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{physics}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    \nabla SA &= \lambda \nabla \\
    \begin{bmatrix} \pdv{SA}{r} \\ \pdv{SA}{h} \\ \end{bmatrix} &=\lambda \begin{bmatrix} \pdv{g}{r} \\ \pdv{g}{h} \\ \end{bmatrix}\\\intertext{Evaluating the partial derivatives of the vectors and stating the constraint equation:}
     4 \pi r + 2 \pi h &= \lambda (2\pi r)\\\tag{14}
     2 \pi r &= \lambda (\pi r^{2}) \tag{15}
    \end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: About the "issue with the tag for some reason, which did not occur anywhere else": It occurs because you've placed `\tag{14}` after rather than before the respective line-break directive.

Comment: I see, it is fixed now. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose this solution, based on the `\medmath` command from `nccmath`, which makes a formula ~80% of \displaystyle, and `cellspace`, with option `[math]`, which ensures a minimal spacing at the top and bottom of tabular cells (and the top and bottom of cells in the various matrix environments, with the option).

Unrelated: if is not necessary to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`, as the latter does it for you (it is a superset of amsmath).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace} 
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\nabla SA &= \lambda \nabla \\
\begin{bmatrix} \medmath{\pdv{SA}{r}} \\ \medmath{\pdv{SA}{h}} \\ \end{bmatrix} &=\lambda \begin{bmatrix} \medmath{\pdv{g}{r}} \\ \medmath{\pdv{g}{h}} \\ \end{bmatrix}\\\intertext{Evaluating the partial derivatives of the vectors and stating the constraint equation:}
 4 \pi r + 2 \pi h &= \lambda (2\pi r)\tag{14} \\
 2 \pi r &= \lambda (\pi r^{2}) \tag{15}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Thanks. This has worked.

Comment: @DhruvNair: I forgot to mention that, generally speaking, I find medium-sized fractions in matrices or arrays look better than displaystyled.

Answer (score 4):

The following screenshot shows your initial use of `bmatrix` environments along with two alternatives. The first prefixes `\displaystyle` to each `\pdv` term and also inserts a bit of vertical whitespace. The second alternative switches from `\frac`-style fraction notation to inline-fraction notation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,physics}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \addlinespace macro
\newcommand\SA{\mathit{SA}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
%% OP's original form
\begin{bmatrix} 
     \pdv{\SA}{r} \\ 
     \pdv{\SA}{h} 
\end{bmatrix} 
&=\lambda 
\begin{bmatrix}  
     \pdv{g}{r} \\ 
     \pdv{g}{h}
\end{bmatrix} \\[2ex]
%% first alternative: use '\displaystyle' (default is '\textstyle')
\begin{bmatrix} 
     \displaystyle\pdv{\SA}{r} \\ \addlinespace
     \displaystyle\pdv{\SA}{h} 
\end{bmatrix} 
&=\lambda 
\begin{bmatrix}  
     \displaystyle\pdv{g}{r} \\ \addlinespace
     \displaystyle\pdv{g}{h}
\end{bmatrix} \\[2ex]
%% second alternative: switch to inline-fraction notation
\begin{bmatrix} 
     \partial\SA/\partial r \\[0.5ex]
     \partial\SA/\partial h 
\end{bmatrix} 
&=\lambda 
\begin{bmatrix}  
     \partial g/\partial r \\[0.5ex]
     \partial g/\partial h
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enough easy solution from [here](https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook)  (page 2 #1.1) (`\resizebox{.2\textwidth}` change .2 in .3 .4 ....):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\nabla SA &= \lambda \nabla \\
\resizebox{.2\textwidth}{!}{ $\begin{bmatrix}\pdv{SA}{r} \\[0.1cm] \pdv{SA}{h} \\ \end{bmatrix}$}  &= 
\resizebox{.2\textwidth}{!}{ $\lambda \begin{bmatrix} \pdv{g}{r} \\[0.1cm] \pdv{g}{h} \\ \end{bmatrix} $}\\
\intertext{Evaluating the partial derivatives of the vectors and stating the constraint equation:}
4 \pi r + 2 \pi h &= \lambda (2\pi r)\\ 
2 \pi r &= \lambda (\pi r^{2})  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should also increase the spacing between the rows of the column vectors.

Comment: yes, thank You @Mico I forgot to add it